# How do I debug a segue from TableViewCell in Xcode?

Tags: debugging, uitableview, ios5, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to implement a segue from one a table view controller to another using storyboard.

I created a push segue from the source tableview cell to my destination table view controller in storyboard, and gave it an identifier.

When I touch a cell in the source tableview, prepareForSegue is called, but the segue never occurs. However, if I change it to a modal segue it works.

Any ideas how I can debug this to find out why it is failing? There's nothing in the debug log...

Comment: Does your source view controller have a navigation controller associated with it?

Comment: The source TableViewController is hosted by a TabViewController. I don't have a navigation controller though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That explains it.  'Push' is specific to navigation controllers.  The following is taken from the Glossary section of the iOS documentation:

"**push segue**  A segue whose transition effect pushes the new view controller onto a navigation stack of a navigation controller."